# Chrome Sync w/o Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I use Chrome on my Linux computer as well as on my Nexus 5. Is there a way I could access my bookmarks, history and open tabs from Chrome Sync on my Raspberry Pi (Chrome is too heavy) or on my server (CLI only) or maybe even on my Nexus S (Chrome too heavy)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yeah. I should have just asked "Is there a way to access my bookmarks […]?"

Comment: I'll edit the question for you and remove my close vote ;) Happy Xmas!

Comment: @DavidPostill, it was irony. Of course the only way to accomplish that would be to have some 3rd party software, and most probably it would be open source.

Comment: Yes, but if you don't **ask for a program**, there is nothing stopping someone suggesting something in the answers. It's a way around the close issue.

Comment: @DavidPostill But I at first ask for such programs already existing, and I do not foreclose a possibility of future creation of such. Anyway — Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you've already read the following ?

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181429
- https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/i50znAY1Zjw
- [Sync Chromium without google account](https://superuser.com/questions/169648/sync-chromium-without-google-account)
- [I'm using Chrome and Chrome Sync; does Google have access to my passwords?](https://superuser.com/questions/753465/im-using-chrome-and-chrome-sync-does-google-have-access-to-my-passwords)

About the closest thing to what you ask for might be the code available in http://damianblog.com/2014/02/09/inside-chrome-sync/ - http://chrync.com/

Comment: Heh, at first I was afraid that I will be now criticized for asking with my search being too little... then I clicked link after link and it turned out I had seen all of them multiple times already :) About to click the last two links now. They seem helpful, judging by just the address ;P